# Incomplete Downloading in Java

Tags: java, download

I want to download an MP3 file using this API

```
https://api.vevioz.com/@api/button/mp3/AKX91G0qNFM
```

I'm using Jsoup to get download URL from buttons. The problem is when I try to download, it downloads only 1.13MB of the MP3 and exits my app.

I've tried all of downloading methods like: Java IO, NIO, AsyncHttpClient, Apache Commons IO.

I really don't know how to successfully download my file and I didn't find any solution on internet for this problem.

My Code:

**JSoup**:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://api.vevioz.com/@api/button/mp3/AKX91G0qNFM").get();
Element body=doc.body();
Elements elements=body.getElementsByClass("download flex flex-wrap sm:inline-flex text-center items-center justify-center");
elements=elements.get(0).children();
String FILE_URL=elements.get(0).attributes().get("href");
String FILE_NAME="./downloads/1.mp3";
```

**Java IO**:

```
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(FILE_URL).openStream());
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME)) {
    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

**NIO**:

```
ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(new URL(FILE_URL).openStream());
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
fileOutputStream.getChannel()
        .transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

**AsyncHttpClient**:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = Dsl.asyncHttpClient();
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);

client.prepareGet(link).execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<FileOutputStream>() {

    @Override
    public State onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart)
            throws Exception {
        stream.getChannel().write(bodyPart.getBodyByteBuffer());
        return State.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileOutputStream onCompleted(org.asynchttpclient.Response response) throws Exception {
        return stream;
    }
});
```

**Apache Commons IO**:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(FILE_URL),new File(FILE_NAME));
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us your code.

Comment: @VGR ok i did what you ask